# How does one implement a function from a namespace?

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, implementation

Essentially, this is my source code.

```
namespace name {  
    int func (void);  
}

int main (void) {  
    name::int func (void) {  
        //body
    }  
    return 0;  
}
```

Now, I want to write that function, declared int the namespace, in a different place.

Answer (score 9):

You can't define the function inside another function like that. There are two options:

Reopen the namespace, and define the function inside it:

```
namespace name {
    int func() {
        // body
    }
}
```

Outside the namespace (and also outside any function or class definition), define it using its fully-qualified name:

```
int name::func() {
    // body
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a function inside a function in C++.

This works

```
namespace name {  
    int func (void);  
}
int name::func (void) {  
        //body
} 
int main (void) {  

    return 0;  
}
```