# Why is it not allowed to put the `static` keyword for class member definitions in namespace scope?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
struct A
{
  static void f();
};

static void A::f() {} //illegal
```

Why's this not allowed? Am asking this because the rule seems inconsistent with other keywords.

You must put `constexpr` on both.

You can put `inline` on both, but you can also omit one of them. This is useful that you can omit `inline` in class definition, which is not important information of the interface.

But the rules for `static` on class members doesn't really make sense. Shouldn't it be consistent with `constexpr`?

I know `static` means internal linkage for namespace-scope functions, and this partly explains the current shape. But isn't distinguishing between free functions and class member functions having no ambiguity in namespace scope? For example, if you write `static void A::f() {}` it's unambiguous that you're defining a member function of A, if A is a class name.

Comment: You might want to add the [tag:language-lawyer] tag.

Comment: Well, how do you define ambiguity? If the standard allowed `static void A::f() {}` and gave it a single meaning, then it wouldn't be ambiguous regardless of what that meaning might be. If you think about what a programmer might reasonably expect `static void A::f() {}` to mean, then it would be ambiguous regardless of what the standard says.

Comment: @WernerHenze That would be an inappropriate tag here. There is no question about what the standard says.

Comment: @hvd Well, I'm asking why things are defined this way in the standard.

Comment: @xiver77 Yeah, I know. That's not what the language-lawyer tag is about. :)

Comment: what bout `virtual`?

Comment: Quite interesting. Would be nice if somebody remembers if there are other examples where a language construct changes meaning based on previous context (it doesn't do, here).

Comment: "*if you write `static void A::f() {}`*" <= you could also mean to [provide the implementation of static function `f()` in namespace `A`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725426/how-does-one-implement-a-function-from-a-namespace) ... and no, don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` in class have other meaning the static in a global or namespace.

when you declared symbol as static in the class, you don't want it to be a global static.

**1. static member**

In the class it is mean the symbol is class related not object related, means for member variable, there is only one instance for all the objects, and for function, it doesn't have access to non static members, which are object oriented. .

**2. static global**

In global scope, the `static` indicate the object or function is local only, and can't be exported (like using `extern`) to other files. in addition it let you use same name in other file for other variable. so if it located in header file, any file including the header, will have different instance of the symbol.

**Therefore** if you were allowed to use it in the global scope for a member, then there was an ambiguity.

Comment: I know what `static` means. My question is that if you write `static void A::f() {}` it's still unambiguous that you're defining a member function of `A`, if `A` is a class name.

Comment: `A` could be a namespace or a class then I'd guess

Answer (score 0):

`static` is not the only specifier that isn't allowed on out-of-line definitions of class member functions. `virtual` and `explicit` are also not.

Basically, specifiers that have a special meaning for class members are not allowed to appear on out-of-line definitions. `static` has a different meaning for class members than for other entities. `virtual` and `explicit` have meaning only for class members. Another way of thinking about it is that these specifiers define the relationship between the function and the class that it belongs to, so they should only appear at the point where the membership of the function in the class is established.

`inline` and `constexpr` have the same meaning for class member functions as for any other function.